# Out of memory issue python inverted index creation

Tags: python, xml, memory-leaks, information-retrieval

This code is intended to create an inverted index but when working with a wikipedia xml dump (~80GB) it runs out of memory. I haven't been able to find out where the memory leak is happening and have explicitly deleted most of the data after using it. The xml dump is parsed using the sax parser, and I've attached the contentHandler and a cleaner class for reference.

**Content handler:**

```py
class Handler(sx.ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self, index_dir):
        self.title = []
        self.body = []
        self.current = ''
        self.id = None
        self.cleaner = CleanerChunker()
        self.pages = 0
        self.index_dir = index_dir
        self.titles = []
        self.keys = ['t', 'b', 'i', 'c', 'r', 'l']
        self.inv_index = {}
    
    # This function is called whenever a page end tag is received
    # It adds the words to the current inverted index which is 
    # written to a file every 1000 pages
    def add_page(self, page=None, force_write=False):
        if page:
            c = 0
            ind = {}
            words = set()
            for key in page.keys():
                temp = {}
                has = {}
                for word in page[key]:
                    flag = False
                    for letter in word:
                        if letter not in has.keys():
                            has[letter] = 0
                        has[letter] += 1
                    for key in has.keys():
                        if has[key] > 5:
                            flag = True
                    has.clear()
                    if flag:
                        continue
                    if word not in temp.keys():
                        temp[word] = 0
                    temp[word] += 1
                    words.add(word)
                ind[self.keys[c]] = temp
                c += 1
                del temp
                del has
                
            for word in words:
                encoding = str(self.pages)
                for key in ind.keys():
                    if word in ind[key].keys():
                        encoding += key + str(ind[key][word])
                if word not in self.inv_index.keys():
                    self.inv_index[word] = []
                self.inv_index[word].append(encoding)
                del encoding
            del ind
            del words
            
        if self.pages % 1000 == 0 or force_write:
            f = open(f'{self.index_dir}/index{int((self.pages+9999)/10000)}.txt', "w")
            for key in sorted(self.inv_index.keys()):
                data = key + ' ' + ' '.join(self.inv_index[key]) + '\n'
                f.write(data)
            self.inv_index.clear()
            f.close()
            
            
        # if self.pages % 10000 == 0 or force_write:
        #     f = open(f'{self.index_dir}/titles{int((self.pages+9999)/10000)}.txt', 'w')
        #     f.write(' '.join(self.titles))
        #     del self.titles
        #     self.titles = []
        #     f.close()
        
        if force_write:
            f = open(f'{self.index_dir}/numdocs.txt', 'w')
            f.write(str(self.pages))
            f.close()
    
    # Function called when parser receives an opening tag
    def startElement(self, tag, attributes):
        self.current = tag
    
    # Function called whenever parser receives a closing tag
    def endElement(self, tag):
        if tag == 'page':
            self.body = ' '.join(self.body)
            self.title = ' '.join(self.title)
            
            #self.titles.append(self.title.lower())
            
            body, infobox, cat, ref, links = self.cleaner.chunk(self.body)
            title = self.cleaner.clean(self.title)

            page = {"title":title, "body":body, "infobox":infobox, 
                    "categories":cat, "references":ref, "links":links}
            
            self.pages += 1
            self.add_page(page=page)
            
            self.title = []
            self.body = []
            self.id = None
        
            if self.pages % 1000 == 0:
                print(f"Successfully parsed {self.pages} pages", flush=True)
        if tag == 'mediawiki':
            self.add_page(force_write=True)
        
    # Function called whenever content is read
    def characters(self, content):
        if self.current == 'id' and not self.id:
            self.id = content
        elif self.current == 'text':
            self.body.append(content)
        elif self.current == 'title':
            self.title.append(content)
        
    def get_file_count(self):
        return int((self.pages+9999)/10000)
```

**Cleaner class:**

```py
from Stemmer import Stemmer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import re

class CleanerChunker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stemmer = Stemmer('english')
        self.stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
        extra_stops = set(['cite', 'https', 'http', 'com', 'url', 'categori'
                                'ref', 'reflist', 'title', 'name', 'author', 
                                'data', 'also', 'link', 'org', 'publish', 'websit',
                                'caption', 'imag', 'infobox', 'wiki'])
        self.stopwords = set.union(self.stopwords, extra_stops)

    # Removes whitespace, non alphanumeric characters and stop words
    def clean(self, text):
        text = text.lower()
        text = re.sub(r'http[^ ]*\ ', r' ', text)
        text = re.sub(r'&lt|&gt|&amp|&quot|&apos|&nbsp', r' ', text)
        text = re.sub(r'[^a-z0-9 ]', r' ', text)
        tokens = text.split()
        tokens_nostop = [word for word in tokens if word not in self.stopwords]
        ret = self.stemmer.stemWords(tokens_nostop)
        del tokens
        del tokens_nostop
        return ret
    
    # Parses the wikipedia body from the entire page
    def get_body(self, text):
        body = []
        prev = 0
        for info in re.finditer(r'\{\{\ *infobox', text):
            body.append(text[prev:info.start()])
            i = info.start()+2
            bracks = 2
            while bracks != 0 and i < len(text):
                if text[i] == '{':
                    bracks += 1
                elif text[i] == '}':
                    bracks -= 1
                i += 1
            prev = i
        body.append(text[prev:])
        del prev
        return self.clean(' '.join(body))
    
    # Parses the infobox from the entire wikipedia body
    def get_infobox(self, text):
        infoboxes = []
        for info in re.finditer(r'\{\{\ *infobox', text):
            i = info.start()+2
            bracks = 2
            while bracks != 0 and i < len(text):
                if text[i] == '{':
                    bracks += 1
                elif text[i] == '}':
                    bracks -= 1
                i += 1
            infoboxes.append(text[info.start():i])
        return self.clean(' '.join(infoboxes))
    
    # Parses the references from the wikipedia body
    def get_references(self, text):
        res = []
        for ref in re.finditer(r'==\ *references\ *==', text):
            next_debar = re.search(r'==\ *[a-z]*\ *==|\[\[category', text[ref.end():])
            if next_debar:
                res.append(text[ref.end():ref.end()+next_debar.start()])
            else:
                res.append(text[ref.end():])
        return self.clean(' '.join(res))
        
    # Parses categories from the wiki body
    def get_categories(self, text):
        ret = re.findall(r'\[\[category:(.*)', text)
        return self.clean(' '.join(ret))
    
    # Parses links from the wiki body
    def get_links(self, text):
        res = []
        for ref in re.finditer(r'==\ *external links\ *==', text):
            next_debar = re.search(r'\[\[category', text[ref.end():])
            if next_debar:
                res.append(text[ref.end():ref.end()+next_debar.start()])
            else:
                res.append(text[ref.end():])
        return self.clean(' '.join(res))
    
    # Takes the wikipedia body as a string and returns separate 
    # strings for each part of the wikipedia article
    def chunk(self, text):
        text = text.lower()
        chunks = (text, "")
        res = re.search(r'==\ *references\ *==', text)
        if res:
            chunks = (text[:res.start()], text[res.start():])
        
        return self.get_body(chunks[0]), \
            self.get_infobox(chunks[0]), \
            self.get_categories(chunks[1]), \
            self.get_references(chunks[1]), \
            self.get_links(chunks[1])
```

Comment: try to use memory profiler - https://towardsdatascience.com/profile-memory-consumption-of-python-functions-in-a-single-line-of-code-6403101db419

Comment: I did, but the output is very hard to understand. Do you have any suggestions on where to add the profile decorators for a better understanding? @balderman